# Verificar se está autenticado

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho a função **autenticar** que verifica se o e-mail e senha digitados conferem com os da tabela users.
O código está funcionando, porém após verificado que e-mail e senha conferem, eu faço um redirect para a view **logado**. Até aí tudo certo. Mas gostaria que essa view não fosse acessada diretamente. Eu gostaria de deixá-la acessível somente para quem está logado. Será que deu para entender?
Pois se eu acessar a url direta dessa view, ela acessa. Quero restringir isso.

```
public function autenticar(Request $request)
{
    //Pego dados do formulário de login e armazeno na variavel $dados
    $dados = $request->except('_token');

    //Depois de armazenar na variavel dados, separo em $email e $password
    $email = $dados['email'];
    $password = $dados['password'];

    //Faz a consulta e verifica se email digitado é igual email do banco
    $query = $this->user->where('email', $email)->first();

    //Verifica se o email existe
    if (!$query)
    {
        return null;
    }

    //Verifica se a senha digitada é igual a senha hash do banco
    if (Hash::check($password, $query->password))
    {
        return redirect()->route('logado');
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Na sua view você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
@if(Auth::check())
   //Conteúdo protegido
@endif

 @if(Auth::guest())
//Conteúdo para não logado(um form de login etc)
@endif
```

Enfim, existem outras maneiras de se fazer algo do tipo mas para fins de aprendizado, é um bom começo.
Dá uma olhada na documentação do laravel, é muito boa.

Comment: Deu certo! Mesmo assim vou ler com mais calma a documentação. Obrigado